# how to crawl a keyword from facebook using php

Tags: php, facebook, dom, web-crawler

i give the keyword can you crawl thru twitter and Facebook to see how many mentions does that have in the past half hour?

can we do that using php ?

Comment: If you are going to crawl Facebook you need written permission according to https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Comment: Thank you dude ! is there any other way to access Facebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Twitter: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/mentions_timeline

For Facebook it´s not possible. The Public Post Search API is deprecated: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

> Public Post search is no longer available.

But you would not get "mentions" anyway. Afaik there is no API on Facebook to get the number of mentions.

There is this one, but only for partners: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/hashtag_counter/v2.1

...not really "mentions" though, just hashtags.

Comment: thank you dude !  but how to use that twitter API in my project there is no API to download , only online console is available

Comment: there are some twitter libraries for php: https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-libraries